# Upload newly installed graphics drivers from command line, and switch afterwards

Tags: command-line, 16.04, drivers, graphics

Using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I have installed the nvidia  driver recommended by [1] using the nvidia graphics ppa [2] but the computer freezes if I log out of my profile; 
not even a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Function key</kbd> responds. 
I do a hard power-down then.
Afterwards it works all as expected.

In the future, though, I would avoid the hard-power down.
I think I could have instructed the system to upload the new drivers gracefully after the installation is complete.

- Which commands would do?

And

- How can I then switch between the previous and the current driver as the need be?

---

[1] `ubuntu-drivers devices`, and recommended driver and version from there

[2] `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nvidia-graphics/ppa; sudo apt get update; sudo apt install nvidia-[recommended version]`

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you use ?

Comment: @JerareYoshi Correction: in that computer it is 16.04 instead of 18.04 as stated earlier